# Throwing Thread was being Aborted exception while running test method in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method `Create` which performs a Db insert. Also I have a delegate `Sampledelegate` where the `Create` method is called in seperate thread.

```
public delegate int Sampledelegate(int num);
class Activity
{
    public int AddNum(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value of Num: {0}", num);
        Object obj = new object();

        Thread newThread = new Thread(this.Create);
        newThread.Start(obj);

        return num;
    }
    void Create(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            Memo memo = (Memo)obj;
            //DAO initialization which internally includes extracting 
            connection to DB
            WorkpacketDao workPacketDao = new WorkpacketDao();
            workPacketDao.CreateMemo(memo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Info(ex.Message);

        }
    }
}
```

Now I have written a test case to check whether it is working fine or not. 
So my test case is

```
public void AddNumTest()
{
    AddNum(1);
    Sampledelegate samdel = new Sampledelegate(AddNum);
}
```

When I run this test case I am getting an exception : `Thread was being aborted` in `create` method.
But when I run the delegate `AddNum` through another method like `main` method, I am not getting this exception .

Calling `AddNum` through another method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Activity activity = new Activity();
    activity.AddNum(1);
    Sampledelegate samdel = new Sampledelegate(activity.AddNum);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this, Why I am getting this exception when I run through test case?
Thanks.

Comment: the `void Create(object obj)` which writes into Db, is it looking for a connection string in `app/web .config?` is the test run from a different project? if both are yes: perhaps the test is trying to find the db connection string in *its* project config, it is not found, and exception thrown which aborts the thread

Comment: The Problem seems to be in the Create-Method rather than the AddNum-Method. Can you show that method too?

Comment: @vladi The Connection strings are written correctly, anyways If I remove the code of thread and simply call Create then it is working fine, I am facing issue only when I call Create in seperate thread.

Comment: You get `ThreadAbortedException` in first case because you wait for the thread completion neither in `AddNum` nor in the `AddNumTest`. In case of `Main` method there is `Console.ReadKey()` which allows thread to finish. You have to rewrite you logic to wait for the thread completion with using `Task` or `async, await` because in current form `AddNum` method makes not much sense.

Comment: @Dmytro Can you please provide me a code snippet of what you are explaining, because I did not get your comment exactly.